# How to link external data source to Google Sheets with API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to link a dataset online to a Google Sheet, so that the Google Sheet automatically pulls data from a particular website.

This is one of the examples of a sheet I am trying to pull data from: https://www.opendata.nhs.scot/dataset/covid-19-in-scotland/resource/7fad90e5-6f19-455b-bc07-694a22f8d5dc

I am confused as to what to do with the codes that it is giving me. I want the latest data from the last day to appear in my Google sheet - is there any way to do this?

Appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: This question is too broad for this forum.  There are many ways to solve your problem but it will involve some research and learning on your part to decide which way is the best for you.  If you are not a programmer then using the google-apps-script tag will most likely result in an answer that you won't understand until you have done some addtional research.  If you need help immediately then I'd recommend contacting one of the top users in this forum to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that website provides a direct URL where then is the date.

```
https://www.opendata.nhs.scot/dataset/b318bddf-a4dc-4262-971f-0ba329e09b87/resource/7fad90e5-6f19-455b-bc07-694a22f8d5dc/download/total_cases_by_hb_20210401.csv
```

So, it should be fairly straightforward to construct that URL for a new date and then using a Trigger at a certain time of the day fire off the function and pull the data down to a sheet of your choosing:

```
function importCSVFromWeb() {
  // Provide the full URL of the CSV file.
  var csvUrl = "https://www.opendata.nhs.scot/dataset/b318bddf-a4dc-4262-971f-0ba329e09b87/resource/7fad90e5-6f19-455b-bc07-694a22f8d5dc/download/total_cases_by_hb_20210401.csv";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

You can change the above to write to a specific sheet instead of the active sheet, you can  store the sheet name in a cell in a "Settings" tab and pass as a parameter

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function importCSVFromWeb() {
  // Provide the full URL of the CSV file.
  var csvUrl = "https://www.opendata.nhs.scot/dataset/b318bddf-a4dc-4262-971f-0ba329e09b87/resource/7fad90e5-6f19-455b-bc07-694a22f8d5dc/download/total_cases_by_hb_20210401.csv";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);

  writeDataToSheet(csvData, "SheetName");
}

// Writes a 2D array of data to sheet
function writeDataToSheet(data, sheetName) {
  goToSheet(sheetName);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  // Leave header row, assume no more than 26 columns and use "Z" for last column
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z");
  range.clear();
  // write date to active sheet starting at the 1st row
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  return sheet.getName();
}

function goToSheet(sheetName) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetName));
}
```

On my automated spreadsheets I always have a tab called Settings and instead of referencing cells using a1Notation, I prefer to use Name Ranges.

Here is an example how to retrieve a value from a cell that has been named, TargetSheet is the name of a specific cell:

```
var sheetName = ss.getRange("TargetSheet").getValue();
```

Then you can use the value in the above function instead of hard coding the sheet.

```
function importCSVFromWeb() {
  // Provide the full URL of the CSV file.
  var csvUrl = "https://www.opendata.nhs.scot/dataset/b318bddf-a4dc-4262-971f-0ba329e09b87/resource/7fad90e5-6f19-455b-bc07-694a22f8d5dc/download/total_cases_by_hb_20210401.csv";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
  var sheetName = ss.getRange("TargetSheet").getValue();
  writeDataToSheet(csvData, sheetName);
}
```